# Can I combine private publishers and public subscribers?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to configure Google Cloud Pub/Sub so that you can have any number of anonymous subscribers to a topic reading messages while the content of the published messages is controlled by an authorized publisher with an account on Google Cloud?

For example, let's say I'm building an application that publishes GOOG stock ticker price every second. I want anyone on the internet to be able to subscribe to my application to get the stock price. However, no applications except my own should be allowed to publish the price. I need to understand if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to setup this kind of message distribution scenario using Google Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM). Once the topic is created (e.g. /topics/goog), the topic needs to be setup with IAM roles/pubsub.publisher permission for your application's account. This can also be a IAM service account for your application.

Next, you will need to create a subscription for the /topics/goog topic (e.g. /subscriptions/goog) and configure the IAM permissions for the subscription. You should give IAM allUsers permission to the /subscriptions/goog topic.

Once this configuration is setup, then only the authorized account will be allowed to publish to /topics/goog and any internet connected user will be allowed to pull messages from /subscriptions/goog

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have a single subscription, then if multiple subscribers pull from that subscription, then the messages will load balance across them; it will not be the case that every subscriber will get all messages. If you want that, then each subscriber needs its own subscription.